# Purpose of NewFormRedirect.aspx

Tags: redirect, newform

What is the purpose of the NewFormRedirect.aspx page located in 
*[Domain]/[Site]/Custom Pages/* folder?

One of our SharePoint users got this page after creating an Item. I tried doing the same and after clicking "save" to create a new (test)item I was redirected to this page briefly before being redirected again to the Display form of the item for the item I had just created.

I found and opened the form in SharePoint Designer and it has a bit of code, but all it does for the user is display.

```
  Content Editor Web Part    

//Set up SPAPI (in my case I have installed SPAPI in Layouts directory)
```

A Google search didn't turn up anything useful besides some Romanian public administrative body with a public accessible SharePoint site which also contained this page, so it must be a default SharePoint page. In which case I wonder why the comments are written in first person, *(I have, I'm using,* etc.)  rather than some official Microsoft code comment style

here is the Romanian page mentioned for reference (the root page reveals that it's Rumanian)
https://www.cjtulcea.ro/sites/cjtulcea/ServiciiElectronice/SiteAssets/Untitled_1.txt

this is the content of the form (located inside the `<content>` tags

```
<![CDATA[//Set up SPAPI (in my case I have installed SPAPI in Layouts directory)
<script src="[Domain Redacted]/Custom_js/SPAPI_Core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[Domain Redacted]/Custom_js/SPAPI_Lists.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//You may need do modify this function depending where your site collection is located
function GetRootUrl() {
    var pathparts = document.location.pathname.split('/');
    var url = 'https://' + document.location.host + '/' + pathparts[1] + '/NEC/TRACK';
    return url;
}

var lists = new SPAPI_Lists(GetRootUrl())

//quering last created item by current user
//i'm using _spUserId to get current user
var items = lists.getListItems(
        'Schools',   // listName
        '',         // viewName
        '<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Lookup">' + _spUserId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>',  // query
        '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ID"/></ViewFields>',  // viewFields
        '1',  // rowLimit
        '<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns></QueryOptions>'  // queryOptions
    );

if (items.status == 200) {
    var rows = items.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('z:row');
    var lastID = rows[0].getAttribute('ows_ID');

    //redirect to wanted page using quered last item ID
    //here i'm redirecting to DispForm.aspx of newly cerated item
    var url = GetRootUrl() + "/Lists/Schools/DispForm_.aspx?ID=" + lastID + "&Source=%2FLists%2FSchools%2FAllItems%2Easpx"
    document.location.href = url;
}
</script>]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a standard SharePoint page. One source could be this: [Redirect from NewForm.aspx to DispForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx of newly created item](https://www.sharepointdrive.com/blog/redirect-from-newform-aspx-to-dispform-aspx-or-editform-aspx-of-newly-created-item/) from [www.sharepointdrive.com](https://www.sharepointdrive.com/blog/redirect-from-newform-aspx-to-dispform-aspx-or-editform-aspx-of-newly-created-item/).

The purpose seems to be to redirect the user creating a new item to the corresponding display/edit form, which can be useful if you're creating some 1-to-many relationship and want to display the children on the same page. Then using the NewForm is a problem due to the lack of an assigned ID.